# Узнать имя рабочей группы

Tags: delphi

Как узнать имя рабочей группы сети, в которой находится компьютер?
Как узнать список рабочих групп, находящихся в сети?

Answer (score 1):

В Windows пуск,панель управления,система, имя компьютера. 
  В любом файловом менеджере (где диски, там значок "сеть"). ТоталКомандер, сеть, вся сеть,
Мicrosoft Windows NetWork.  Увидите группы, которые существуют в вашей сетке IP адресов.

Comment: так...прошу прощения... неправильно поставил вопрос... имя рабочей группы надо узнать средствами дельфи.

Answer (score 1):

```
function TForm1.GetNTDomainName: string;
  var hReg: TRegistry;
begin
  hReg := TRegistry.Create;
  hReg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  hReg.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon', false);
  Result := hReg.ReadString('DefaultDomainName');
  hReg.CloseKey;
  hReg.Destroy;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот код получает рабочую группу и имена всех компьютеров в ней. Выводит в TreeViev.

А IP по Имени компьютера найти проще.
Вот исходник

**www.connecter.16mb.com/NET**

На форме treeview1, edit1, button, библиотека WinSock2

Добавить в папку с проектом библиотеку WinSock2.
Добавить в Uses WinSock2.

При нажатии на кнопку идёт получение всех имен компьютеров

```
treeview1.Items[0].DeleteChildren;
treeview1.Items[0].Text:=edit1.Text;
FindAllComputers(edit1.Text);
```

Добавить Тип и Переменные

```
type

  PWkstaInfo = ^TWkstaInfo;
  TWkstaInfo = record
    wki100_platform_id  : DWORD;
    wki100_computername : PWideChar;
    wki100_langroup     : PWideChar;
    wki100_ver_major    : DWORD;
    wki100_ver_minor    : DWORD;
  end;

  function NetWkstaGetInfo(ServerName: PWideChar; Level: DWORD;
Bufptr: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll';

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Info: PWkstaInfo;
  Error: DWORD;
```

Получение Раб.Группы (Form1.Create)

```
Error := NetWkstaGetInfo(nil, 100, @Info);
if Error <> 0 then
raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(Error));
Edit1.Text:= info^.wki100_langroup;
```

Процедура

```
     procedure FindAllComputers(Workgroup: String);
var
  Computer: array[1..500] of string[25];
  ComputerCount: integer;
  EnumHandle: THandle;
  WorkgroupRS: TNetResource;
  Buf: array[1..500] of TNetResource;
  BufSize: cardinal;
  Entries: cardinal;
  Result: integer;
  i: integer;
  Chl:ttreenode;
  DelProcValue:string;
begin
   ComputerCount := 0;
   Workgroup := Workgroup + #0;
   FillChar( WorkgroupRS, SizeOf( WorkgroupRS ) , 0 );
   With WorkgroupRS do
   begin
      dwScope := 2;
      dwType := 3;
      dwDisplayType := 1;
      dwUsage := 2;
      lpRemoteName := @Workgroup[1];
   end;
   WNetOpenEnum( RESOURCE_GLOBALNET, RESOURCETYPE_ANY, 0, @WorkgroupRS, EnumHandle );
   Repeat
      Entries := 1;
      BufSize := SizeOf( Buf );
      Result := WNetEnumResource( EnumHandle, Entries, @Buf, BufSize );
      If ( Result = NO_ERROR ) and ( Entries = 1 ) then
      begin
         Inc( ComputerCount );
         Computer[ComputerCount] := StrPas( Buf[1].lpRemoteName );
      end;

   Until ( Entries <> 1 ) or ( Result <> NO_ERROR );
   WNetCloseEnum( EnumHandle );
   for i := 1 to ComputerCount do
     begin
     Chl:= form1.TreeView1.Items.AddChild(form1.TreeView1.Items[0],Computer[i]);
     chl.ImageIndex:=1;
     chl.selectedindex:=1;
     DelProcValue:=chl.Text;
     delete(DelProcValue,1,2);

     end;

end;
```